# How to copy sheet to it's own workbook on a Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to copy each sheet in a workbook to it's own workbook. I want the new workbooks to be in the same folder as the original.

I found a video online and copied the code for PC, except for path.

On the `Worksheet.Copy` method, I get the following error:
[image]

I did a `Debug.Print` of the original workbook's full name and the name of each sheet and all is correct.

Why can't Excel navigate to this location, it is already there?

```vb
Sub CopySheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name
        Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    
        ws.Copy      'THIS LINE PRODUCES ERROR SHOWN ABOVE
        
        ChDir "/Users/phild/Documents/CopyToNewWB/"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="/Users/phild/Documents/CopyToNewWB/" & ActiveSheet.Name & "xlsx"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Are any of the sheets in the workbook hidden?

Comment: No Hidden sheets

Comment: Missing period? `& ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsx"`

Comment: try using the full path

Comment: Thanx but the missing "." did not fix the issue

Comment: Also the full path name didn't help either. It was only missing "Macintosh HD"